# crystal report pdf preview font family is different

Tags: asp.net, pdf, browser, fonts, crystal-reports

I need help. I am generating PDF from crystal report. Crystal report preview is same everywhere (font family is "Arila Narrow") but pdf preview font family is different in different browsers.

- Chrome and Firefox shows "Calibri (Body)"
- Safari shows "ArialNarrow"    (not Arial Narrow)

But I need preview font in "Arila Narrow". how can I control it.
"Arial Narrow" is already installed on server and applied on crystal report fields

I searched it over internet net but could not find solution.
Please guide

Comment: As currently state, this is not a programming question, but just a "how do I use this software" question, better suited for another place like https://superuser.com or the likes. The most obvious solution is to ask crystal reports how to do this thing, and failing that, a crystal reports community (forum, irc, whathaveyou). Until it becomes and actual *programming* problem, Stackoverflow is not the place to ask.

Comment: ok. @Mike'Pomax'Kamermans Thanks. I posted this at superuser.com. Waiting for solution